# Filtering out Repeated Characters in Java

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to write a program that has the method `public static void method(List<String> words)` where the parameter `words` is a list of words from the text file `words.txt` that are sorted and contain only the words where each letter occurs only once. For example, the word "feel" would not be included in this list since "e" occurs more than once. The word list is not to be used as an argument in the rest of the program, so the method `method` is only to be used to store and remember the wordlist for later use. This function can also perform any of the sorting methods.

My thought process was to create a method that would read the text file, and use that text file as the argument in `method`. `method` would then filter out all words with letters that appear more than once, and also sort the new list.

When running the program, I'm getting an error "java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null (in java.util.LinkedList$Listltr)" on the line `for (String word : words)`. Also does the line `public static List list;` properly save and store the `list` for later use?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class ABC
{
    public static List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>()
    public static List readFile()
    {
        String content = new String(); 
        File file = new File("words.txt");
        LinkedList<String> words = new LinkedList<String>();

        try
        {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file));
            while (sc.hasNextLine())
            {
                content = sc.nextLine();
                words.add(content);
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException fnf)
        {
           fnf.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("\nProgram terminated safely");
        }  
        for (String word : words) 
        {
            if (letters(word) == false) 
            {
                list.add(word);
            }
        }
        Collections.sort(list);
        return list;
    }

    public static boolean letters(String word)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length() - 1; i++) 
        {
            if (word.contains(String.valueOf(word.charAt(i))) == true) 
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println(readFile());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an iterator. Try it like this.

```
        Iterator<String> it = words.iterator(); 
        while(it.hasNext()) {

            CharSequence ch = it.next();
            for (int j = 0; j < ch.length(); j++)
            {
                for (int k = j + 1; k < ch.length(); k++)
                {
                    if (ch.charAt(j) == ch.charAt(k))
                    {
                        it.remove(word);
                    }
                }
            }
            list.add(word);
        }
```

However, I would approach it differently.

```
        String[] data =
                { "hello", "bad", "bye", "computer", "feel", "glee" };

        outer: for (String word : data) {
            for (int i = 0; i < word.length() - 1; i++) {
                if (word.charAt(i) == word.charAt(i + 1)) {
                    System.out.println("dropping '" + word + "'");
                    continue outer;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Keeping '" + word + "'");
            List.add(word);
        }
```

Note: You used `feel` as an example so it wasn't clear if you wanted to check for the same letter `anywhere` in the word or only `adjacent` letters that are the same.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I have updated my code trying to utilize all the answers given. I'm not getting any errors now, but it seems like I'm still getting words that contain some of the same letters. And you're correct, it should be filtering out repeated letters ```anywhere``` in the word.

Comment: Use an array of size 256 and create it for each word.  It initializes by default to 0's  Then when you get a character, use that character as an index into the array to increment the array by one.  Then check to see if that value is >= 2.  You only need a single loop for that.

Comment: i'm having a hard time visualizing this. what would that be achieving? also I'm updating my code once again, since I realized that my if statement wasn't finding if the characters were ANYWHERE within the word

Comment: Since it uses the index of the character to reference an array slot, it actually counts the number of times per word a character is used.  So each time you increment the index say for 'd' you know that 'd' appeared that many times.  So right after adding one to that slot, check to see if is >= 2.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with you program:

- `public static List list;`
  Whenever you see a collection (like List) without a generics - it's a bad smell. Should be
   `public static List<String> list;`
  Also consider changing `public` to `private`.

- In readFile() method you mask the class variable 'list' with a local variable 'list'. So your class variable remains uninitialized:
  `list = new LinkedList<String>();`

- Better use try-with-resources for scanner:
  `try(Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file))) {`
  You don't need to close it afterwards manually.
- You cannot modify the list through which you are iterating. You should either use an iterator and its `remove` method, or create a new list and append good words to it, instead of removing bad words from the original list.

```
public static List<String> readFile() {
  File file = new File("words.txt");
  List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
  try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)) {
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
      String word = scanner.nextLine();
      if (noDuplicates(word)) {
        list.add(word);
      }
    }
    Collections.sort(list);
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("File not found");
  }
  return list;
}

private static boolean noDuplicates(String word) {
  Set<Character> distinctChars = new HashSet<>();
  for (char c : word.toCharArray()) {
    if (!distinctChars.add(c)) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I have updated my code trying to utilize all the answers given. I'm not getting any errors now, but it seems like I'm still getting words that contain some of the same letters.

Comment: @NikeDog I updated the answer with a possible implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The source of the error is that you are changing a list that you are iterating on.  This is generally not a good idea.

Since you are building a new list, you don't actually need to change the one you are iterating on. I would recommend changing your code so that the logic for deciding if a letter appears more than once goes in a separate method. This way the complexity of any given method is manageable, and you can test them separately.

So create a new method that tests if any letter appears more than once:

```
static boolean doesAnyLetterAppearMoreThanOnce(String word) {
    ...
}
```

Then you can use it in your existing method:

```
    for (String word : words) {
        if (!doesAnyLetterAppearMoreThanOnce(word)) {
            list.add(word);
        }
    }
    Collections.sort(list);
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I have updated my code trying to utilize all the answers given. I'm not getting any errors now, but it seems like I'm still getting words that contain some of the same letters.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this shorter approach:

```
public static void method(List<String> words) {
words.removeIf(word -> {
    Set<Integer> hs = new HashSet<>();
    return word.chars().anyMatch(c -> {
        if (hs.contains(c)) return true;
        else hs.add(c);
        return false;
    });
});
System.out.println(words);}
```

words List now contain only the words where each letter occurs only once.